# How to get single item from SharePoint document library using SPQuery (without using for loop)?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Sometimes there is a requirement to get only one SharePoint item from a large document library. So, how to get single item from SharePoint document library using SPQuery (without using for loop)?

Answer (score 1):

SPList class has several methods for getting only single item:

- [GetItemByIdSelectedFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyidselectedfields(v=office.15).aspx)
- [GetItemByIdAllFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyidallfields(v=office.15).aspx)
- [GetItemById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyid(v=office.15).aspx)
- [GetItemByUniqueId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyuniqueid(v=office.15).aspx)

Except the last one they need integer ID (ID property of SPListItem) of item. The last one uses the guid ID (UniqueId property of SPListItem).

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the C# code to achieve the above requirement:**

```
public SPListItemCollection GetSpecificLibraryItem(fileName)
{
SPList list = web.Lists["MyDocName"];
SPQuery dQuery = new SPQuery();
dQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
string QueryString = "<Where>" +
                      "<Eq>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\"/>" +
                        "<Value Type=\"Text\">" + fileName + "</Value>" +
                      "</Eq>" +
                     "</Where>";
         dQuery.Query = QueryString;
        SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.GetItems(dQuery);
  return collListItems;
}
```